# Pre-generating a JSF based web app for better performance and offline mode

Tags: jsf, web-applications, iphone-web-app, offline-browsing

I have a JSF web application, where the dynamic content is based on data taken from a database.
Since all the data is available in advance, I would like to see if there is a way to pre-generate all the pages into their final HTML format on the server, so that the user experiences much better performance and doesn't have to wait for the page generation.
Moreover - my app is running on mobile devices and I want to have the option of using it offline, by downloading everything to the device in advance (assume I don't need any business logic to work at real time).

So, I'm not talking here about the built-in caching of JSF - I'm looking for a kind of method that converts a JSF app into some static website that works much faster and can run offline as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 for offline cache.

See a few articles about it here:

1. [Tutorial](http://blog.cubeanywhere.com/2010/10/html5-offline-webapps-practical-example.html)
2. [Tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/)

There are more examples on the internet for HTML5 and working offline